# Multiplication of list of iterator

Tags: python, list

I am having some trouble to understand what is happening with the following code:

```
>>> print(list(zip(*[iter((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))]*4)))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
>>> print(list(zip(*[iter((1,2,3,4,5,6,7))]*4)))
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

I suspect it is doing internally something like:

```
>>> print(list(zip(*((1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)))))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

But I can't understand how this list of iterator multiplied by a constant gives this.
Could you clarify this for me?

Comment: @mkrieger1: That shows the end result, but the OP seems curious about how it works, not what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it's doing is equivalent to:

```
myiter = iter((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
print(list(zip(myiter, myiter, myiter, myiter)))
```

The original syntax is just using [star unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/364696) with a multiplied `list` containing four references to the same underlying iterator.

So when `zip` is pulling the elements for each `tuple`, it's pulling from the same, stateful iterator for each one, advancing the iterator as it goes. Thus, it gets `(1, 2, 3, 4)` when pulling the first, second, third and fourth elements for the first `tuple`.

The call to `iter` here is important, as is the multiplication; it ensures there is exactly one iterator involved, repeated multiple times, so all the arguments to `zip` share the same underlying state. If `iter()` wasn't called, `zip` would be making its own four independent iterators for the `tuple`, each of which would advance separately.

Comment: thank you. The key point for me is the phrase: "it's pulling from the same, stateful iterator for each one, advancing the iterator as it goes"